# Domo: how to identify recently deleted cards

Tags: card, domo

I recently deleted a lot of cards. Is there a way in Domo to identify recently deleted cards/reports? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option to see the cards you deleted. One thing you may do is reach out to the Domo Support team if the card settings are available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity Log (https://instancename.domo.com/admin/logging) will show you any cards that have been deleted.
You can filter to 'Type' = 'Deleted card' to find them, then to get the card IDs you can download the filtered list as a csv file from the UI.

If by any chance the Activity Log is not enabled in your instance you can request this via Support / CSM.